Problemas al migrar una tabla de 1.2 TB desde Informix a PostgreSQL. Configuración de memoria y optimización
verán estoy trabajando en la migración de una tabla grande (aproximadamente 1.2 TB con unas 230 millones de lineas, donde cada linea es un objeto a insertar) desde Informix a PostgreSQL y me he encontrado con algunos problemas. Actualmente estoy usando pgloader 3.6.2 para cargar por partes un archivo de carga que genero Informix (el cual particione en unas 15 partes por su peso y es prácticamente CSV) El archivo de carga de pgloader lo tengo configurado de la siguiente forma:
LOAD CSV
    FROM '/workarea/bkp_postgres/bd_data_migra1.txt'
    WITH ENCODING iso-8859-1
INTO postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/bd
    TARGET TABLE bd_table
WITH
    fields not enclosed,
    fields terminated by '|',
    batch rows = 100000,
    workers = 48,
    concurrency = 4,
    batch size = 512MB;

El problema con esa configuración es que ademas de tardar casi 7 horas por archivo, si elevo mucho algunos parámetros como concurrency o batch rows me da un error del estilo:
fatal error encountered in SBCL pid 24973(tid 140736921958144): Heap exhausted, game over.
Ademas de que desconozco si es por la versión pero no me reconoce otras configuraciones como work_mem, (las cuales estaba intentando trabajar aparte con el archivo postgresql.conf pero supongo que eso ya es otro tema).
Como nota el servidor de postgres tiene 56 cpus 28 cores per socket y 2 hilos por nucleo, ademas de contar con unos 115GB de ram disponibles, pero al ver el rendimiento con top al ejecutar la carga con pgloader solo me muestra un uso de cpu del %118 máximo (lo cual interpreto como un solo cpu al máximo y un 18% de otro) y normalmente menos del 1% de ram.
Si alguien tiene alguna recomendación para hacer la migración de manera mas optima aunque no sea necesariamente con pgloader lo agradecería muchísimo.

Desactiva si es posible los indices de la tabla en PostgreSQL, deshabilita el autovacuum para esa tabla.
Preguntas:

¿Que error te muestra los logs de PostgreSQL?
¿Que versión de postgres estas usando?

Has probado o visto la herramienta alternativa pg_bulkload

Hola, veras en la configuración de pgloader también añadí drop indexes; , pero no mejoro casi nada el tiempo de carga, en cuanto a tus preguntas. como tal no tengo logs de error en postgres pero intente hacer la carga con COPY y tengo una inconsistencia, veras al hacer wc -l bd_data_migra1.txt para obtener las lineas me da un total de 22131564, pero cuando termina la carga y hago un select count (*) from BD; me da 22405553 inserciones (ademas de algunos problemas extra que no me alcanza a poner en este comentario).

Por cierto, algunos de esos problemas se deben a que uno de los campos de la tabla tiene un  con un montón de cosas dentro, el delimitador de mi CSV es un | pero hay algunos registros en ese campo que contienen | y me parece que por eso fallan al momento de hacer el COPY*. Cabe mencionar que no me cierro a la herramienta o forma de migrar los datos, bien puede ser con algún programa externo que me recomienden y funcione, y olvide mencionarlo, la versión de postgres es la 15.3

sobre el tema del delimitador | puede ser un problema en tu caso si ese campo contiene registros con ese caracter, solo para una prueba, intenta crear una tabla nueva con un solo campo de tipo text, e importa los datos usando COPY  un delimitador bastatnte raro, como por ejemplo: ^ y verifica si la cantida de registro es la que esperas.
te comentaba de pg_bulkload, pues tiene algunas opciones de importacion que te permite mejorar un poco la velocidad de carga de los datos
